# How do I restrict a user to view other users data?

Tags: permissions, users

Can i restrict one user to view other users file and folder in centos and other user unable to view first user files and folder. Means both user's files and folder hidden from each other but superuser/root can view both of them files and folder.

In other words, I'm thinking of having two groups `(say NormalUsers1 and NormalUsers2)`. The `NormalUser1` group will have the users `user1`. And `NormalUser2` group will have the users `user2`. 
The `Superuser` group will only have the user `root`. Now, I need the `Superuser` to have full access on the files of users in the group `NormalUsers1` and `NormalUsers2`. But both `NormalUsers1` and `NormalUsers2` cannot access and view each other files and folders.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `root` user have full access to everything in the system, so you don't have to do anything to allow him the see anything.

To prevent users in group `NormalUsers1` from seeing files that belong to group `NormalUsers2` simply give to those files 0 on the others field

```
chmod xx0 files
```

For more info about file permissions in linux: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your second point regarding normal users.

Comment: This links has more information about file permissions http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: rlinux57, you may want to read up on file permissions.  What 
 Mhd Wissam Al-Roujoulah was trying to say was that by breaking up the users into different groups, they wouldn't be able to view each other's files if the permissions were set accordingly.
Also reco you read up on `umask` to see if you went to set a default system umask.

Comment: I gave 0770 access to folder so that user2 cannot access it, only `group1` (user1 and root) can accessed. But user2 is able to view it. Remember I need to hide the file/dir from a SPECIFIC user2/group2.